# How to stream the desktop using FFMPEG , and set the output to http://127.0.0.1:8080

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, stream

i am trying to use FFMPEG on windows to stream my entire desktop, through my localhost address : 127.0.0.1:8080 , and it will be accessible from another computer in the same network , using vlc by opening network url, or embed it in a source video file for exemple.
i tried the commande here :

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 6 -i desktop output.mp4
```

but this record the entire desktop (what i want to do) and store it in ouput.mp4 file , i tried changing it to :

```
    ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 6 -i desktop http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

but i get this error :

[gdigrab @ 0000023b7ee4e540] Capturing whole desktop as 1920x1080x32 at (0,0)
[gdigrab @ 0000023b7ee4e540] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, gdigrab, from 'desktop':
Duration: N/A, start: 1625841636.774340, bitrate: 398133 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: bmp, bgra, 1920x1080, 398133 kb/s, 6 fps, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn
[NULL @ 0000023b7ee506c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'
http://127.0.0.1:8080: Invalid argument

but i want to set the output as  : http://127.0.0.1:8080
how should i do that ?

**Update :**
I found this command :

ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop -vcodec mpeg4 -q 12 -f mpegts http://127.0.0.1:8080

it seems to stream, but i am not able to open it from nor vlc nor media player

Answer (score 0):

I used instead HLS for HTTP Live Stream with ffmpeg, for recording screen and store .ts and .m3u8 files in a folder in the local machine.
And then self host the application (specify the root directory) using [NancyServer](https://volkanpaksoy.com/archive/2015/11/11/building-a-simple-http-server-with-nancy/), pointing to the .m3u8 file.
Each time the local machine start streaming, the folder will be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from this helpful [post](https://superuser.com/a/1556306/1320270), I was able to share my desktop of my server Win10 machine to my client Win10 machine.

Win10 machine stream/server:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -i desktop -vcodec mpeg4 -q 12 -f mpegts udp://20.20.5.5:6666
```

Win10 machine play/client:

```
ffplay -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:6666
```

My Win10 machine that is streaming/server ip address is `20.20.5.111` while the Win10 machine that is recieving/playing/client is `20.20.5.5`.

As mentioned from another [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1607993/unable-to-open-ffmpeg-mpegts-stream-on-a-udp-port-on-windows), using localhost/`127.0.0.1` was the way to get the client to stream the video.

Answer (score 0):

Overview.
First, you need a local server to host your streams.
Second, you start the stream.

Details.

1. Start the local server: use [MediaMTX standalone](https://github.com/bluenviron/mediamtx?tab=readme-ov-file#standalone-binary:%7E:text=and%20OpenWrt%20binary.-,Standalone%20binary,-Download%20and%20extract).
2. Publish the stream:

   ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i ANY-FILE.mp4 -c copy -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream